# Google Cloud Speech to text error : Long duration elapsed without audio

Tags: python, google-cloud-speech

I am trying to convert group discussion into text in real time using the Google Cloud speech to text with infinite streaming tutorial (python version).
However, I am frequently getting the following error.
So, I currently repeatedly restart the system when it stops.

I think that the cause of this error is that the client side cannot send the audio data to the server side for about 10 seconds.
How can I improve this?

Devices：
raspberry Pi 4 (3 units) (one for each participant)

Error timing：
Erratic
(sometimes the error occurs about 8 minutes after the program starts, sometimes it occurs about 3 minutes after the program starts. Sometimes it runs for the full 30 minutes.)
(Also, when an error occurs in one device, there is a high probability that other devices will also stop with errors.)

Source code: python version
https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/endless-streaming-tutorial?hl=ja

```
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mugenstreaming.py", line 293, in <module>
    main()
  File "mugenstreaming.py", line 276, in main
    listen_print_loop(responses, stream)
  File "mugenstreaming.py", line 175, in listen_print_loop
    for response in responses:
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 116, in next
    six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
google.api_core.exceptions.OutOfRange: 400 Audio Timeout Error: Long duration elapsed without audio. Audio should be sent close to real time.
```